# Error compiling code in c++ using gmp

Tags: c++, gmp

I copied a code that compiles and runs well from one computer to another, I installed the GMP library correctly. I'm tying to compile the code via `g++ -o code -I/path/to/library code.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp`, I get the error `invalid suffix '_mpf' on floating constant`. Obviously I'm using `_mpf`, I don't understand why my code compiles and runs fine on one computer and not the other.

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using? Versions before 5 didn't have C++11 enabled by default, and lacked many C++11 features anyway. And suffixes like that is a C++11 feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[User-defined suffixes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) are a C++11 feature. Add `-std=c++11` to your compiler invocation.

You're not getting an error from the headers trying to define these operators because the operators are [conditionally compiled](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-6.1/file/tip/gmpxx.h#l2005) only if you're compiling with C++11 support.